# Azure AD B2C AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId technical profile is throwing error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy with below technical profile to enable login from multiple Azure AD tenants. When I login with a valid work account the technical profile AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId is throwing an error. I have included the app insights output below. Since I have no control on how Azure AD B2C builds the graph api lookup within the technical profile, how can I go about finding and fixing the actual issue?

I checked the claim transformation that builds up the alternative security ID and found nothing, followed the starter pack and did not change anything

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
          <DisplayName>Active Directory</DisplayName>
          <!-- <DisplayName>Sign In</DisplayName> -->
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">dcaee4b4-61d6-45e6-88b2-b35a81e93077</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>

            <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">
              https://sts.windows.net/{GUID1-masked},
              https://sts.windows.net/{GUID2-masked},
              https://sts.windows.net/{GUID3-masked},
              https://sts.windows.net/{GUID4-masked}
            </Item>

            <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
            <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>-->
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AZB2CSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
            <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" /> -->
            <!-- Mark:  issuerUserId below originally mapped to sub -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" /> -->
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

"AAD Request to [https://graph.windows.net/34d8169d-0e97-4cc7-a8d0-57c29404f1b1/users?api-version=1.6-integrationOnly&%24filter=alternativeSecurityIds%2fany(x%3ax%2ftype+eq+6+and+x%2fidentityProvider+eq+%27https%3a%2f%2fsts.windows.net%{GUID-MASKED}%2f%27+and+x%2fkey+eq+X%2738623361343134642D623331622D343638322D396662382D663461376161666164643966%27)](https://graph.windows.net/34d8169d-0e97-4cc7-a8d0-57c29404f1b1/users?api-version=1.6-integrationOnly&%24filter=alternativeSecurityIds%2fany(x%3ax%2ftype+eq+6+and+x%2fidentityProvider+eq+%27https%3a%2f%2fsts.windows.net%%7BGUID-MASKED%7D%2f%27+and+x%2fkey+eq+X%2738623361343134642D623331622D343638322D396662382D663461376161666164643966%27)) **using method GET as request body is malformed**.\r\nResponse: \n{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/34d8169d-0e97-4cc7-a8d0-57c29404f1b1/$metadata#directoryObjects","value":[]}\r\n",

And after policy runs the error that is displayed to the app/user is : AADB2C99002: An account could not be found for the provided user ID. which is normal I guess as the user look up fails

Answer (score 0):

"Open your browser and go to the OpenID Connect metadata URL for the tenant. Find the **issuer object** and record its value. It should look similar to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/.well-known/openid-configuration"](https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/.well-known/openid-configuration%22).

When I do that, I get an issuer like:

"https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID/v2.0"

But you have:

[https://sts.windows.net/{GUID1-masked}](https://sts.windows.net/%7BGUID1-masked%7D)

(The documentation seems wrong anyway - their issuer is the "well-known" address).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be calling `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId`, you chould instead call `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError` in the case of social logins, like [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L458).

See the [social login journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L665) here for comparison from the Starter Pack.

There is a full explanation here of how this works in the [readme](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/readme.md).

Comment: Thank you, I am actually calling it but left it out. If I use the -no error one it passes through the next step which is AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress and it throws a similar graph API error when checking the app insights. Why would a query by email throw "graph api query body malformed" error?

Comment: Is this the first time the user is logging in? If so, you cannot expect to read the user and it return success, it will fail. Setup your preconditions such that you only read the user when they are signing in.

Comment: No it is not, I see a user entry in the directory. My question is really the internal errors B2C is throwing. Why would the graph api query body be malformed? It is not simply returning "no user found" so knowing there is a user I really want to understand why the technical profiles find by alternative security id or find by email not working and throwing errors

Comment: I suspect you are searching by email, but when you created the user, the email is not written  (by `AAD-UserWriteAltSecurityIdUsingObjectId`) to the identities/signInNames collection of the user object. To make graph call work, you need to fix the logic. Have you stored the email on the account? Where is it stored? Are you searching by the correct attribute name to find the email on the user?